# FCM cloud Functions Get child(created by Auto Id) in node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am using FCM cloud functions to detect writes in my messages node and send push notification if there is a new message and device is offline.

In tutorials online I found that all the nodes/childs have meaningful names instead of auto generated child IDs. My db architecture is this: 
[image: FireBase DB Messages Node].

Can you please tell me how to get every next child without knowing the names(because child names are random and autogenerated). So that I can access and detect writes and send push notifications.

Thanks in advance.